# How do edits influence bounty timing?

Tags: support, bounties

I'm not sure, but I think it takes some time before users can attach bounties to unanswered questions. Is this time calculated from the moment the question was initially asked, or the time of the most recent edit of the OP? And how long is that time period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the time is calculated from the time when question is posted first time.

From [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) -

> - Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
> - Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
> - There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.
> - Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
> - After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
> - If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Answer (score 4):

The time is calculated from the initial asking of the question.

From the ["How does the bounty system work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) question.

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked